# Irreducibility of a general fibre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A\subseteq B$ be an inclusion of affine domains over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$. Can someone give me a *reference* for the following fact?

If $A$ is algebraically closed in $B$, then a general fibre over Spec $A$ is irreducible, i.e., there exists an open set $V\subseteq Spec A$, such that for any prime ideal $p\in V$, the extended ideal $pB$ is a primary ideal. Also it would be helpful to know if the assertion holds in any greater generality.